# Error when trying to display a widget containing an image that is created by another module in customtkinter, Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, module, customtkinter

I'm trying to display an a widget containing an image in the window created by my main script, by calling a function from another module.
But I'm getting the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

This Error only occurs with widgets that contain images.

The main.py script that creates the window and calls the function from the module.

```
from customtkinter import *
import image_script

window = CTk()
window.geometry("1400x1000")


image_script.call_image()


window.mainloop()
```

The image_script.py that contains the function which creates and displays the widget.

```
from customtkinter import *
from PIL import Image


def call_image():
    from main import window
    image_example = CTkImage(Image.open("images/icon_example.png"), size=(150, 100))
    image_label = CTkLabel(window, image=image_example)
    image_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=2, anchor="center")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the newer version of customtinker module supports opening the image from the image path directly. But this newer version doesn't come along with the python standard library. It needs to be installed.

The customtinker module which comes along with the python installation is the older version. It can't open directly from the path. It can handle only photoimage. Also, the older version is meant for adding images to button and all.

To handle photoimage other than buttons, you don't need customtinker module. you can do it with tkinter itself. Converting to PhotoImage is done by PIL.ImageTk.

Another problem: you've used place method and rely=2, you've given. rely is the relative y-coordinate. It takes value between 0 and 1. If you mention 2, It goes outside the window.

Also, it is better not to declare the image path as string. Because in windows os(in case if the project is used in windows), the path  is separated by back slashes(\). Whereas in linux and unix based os, it is separated by forward slashes(/). This can be taken care by python's os module with .path.join() method.

This is how the code should be:

main.py:

```
#main.py

from tkinter import *
from image_script import call_image

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1400x1000")

call_image(window)

window.mainloop()
```

#image_script.py

```
#image_script.py

from tkinter import *
import PIL.Image as im
import PIL.ImageTk as imgtk
import os





def call_image(window):
   
    
    #get current working directory
    
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    
    #Assuming that the images folder is in your current working directory, get image_path
    
    img_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'images', 'icon_example.png')
    
    #open image with PIL.Image
    img = im.open(img_path)
    
    #Resize
    img = img.resize((150,100))
    
    #Convert into Photoimage using PIL.ImageTK 
    image_example = imgtk.PhotoImage(img)
    
    #image label
    image_label = Label(window, image=image_example)


    #the following line is important as this function will be imported in main.py
    #It prevents garbage_collection
    
    image_label.photo = image_example
    
    #Place image and label
    image_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
```

checked with a dummy icon image and works perfectly. [See the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/iKg5jjo)

Edit:
Also you can see that I've added 'window' argument to the function. That is because, If the function and design-part are there in a same file: When you ask the function to place the image in window, the function will know what is window variable. Because you would have mentioned 'window=Tk()' in the same file. But since function is written in another file, the function won't know what you mean by window. So, I've given it as an argument. And after impoting while calling the function, I've given this window(ie Tk()) is the argument of the function.

Comment: I think you are confusing `tkinter` with `customtkinter`. `tkinter` is a standard library unlike `customtkinter` which OP is trying to use. Note that `customtkinter` uses `tkinter`.

Comment: @TheLizzard This is the standard library version of customtkinter: https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/0.3/.  This comes along with the python standard library. You can see a link over there for newer version. This newer version needs to be installed. This is the newer version document: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/.  I searched because I was wondering why he needed another module when these things can be done with tkiner itself.

Comment: And the link of the newer version given is not official Pypi website. After seeing this, I modified the code with tkinter. Also please see that in the older version documents, the image option is available only for buttons. That too the images can be handled only after converting into photoimage with some other module.

Comment: Libraries on PyPI aren't part of the [python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). Also I think that OP wants a solution with `customtkinter` as it's supposed to look more modern.

Comment: Thank you. After seeing your comment I checked from the terminal. Pl see the screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/3KO2zeS.  If I import tkinter, there is no import error. But with customtkinter, it gives import error saying no module named customtkinter. Not just its official page, other google results also says it needs to be installed. I agree the questioner may prefer customtkinter. At least this info may make him to check which version of tkinter is installed. Also I've corrected few other mistakes which were causing errors. So, I feel my answer will be useful.

Comment: Thanks it works all I had to do was placing the window parameter in the image_script.call_image(window) call like in your example instead of importing the window from inside the function.